# Javascript Condition - Not hiding ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide the ID "hide-homepage" and it's working overall, except for my second condition where I want to hide it at the stated URL (http://wgzrv.ndxva.servertrust.com/login.asp).  Am I missing something?

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(window).resize(function(){ 
        function showMyDiv() {
        if (window.location.href == "http://wgzrv.ndxva.servertrust.com") && (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 992) { 
        document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="none";
        } else if (window.location.href == "http://wgzrv.ndxva.servertrust.com/login.asp") {
        document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="none";
        } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 992) {
        document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="none";
        } else {
        document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="block";
            }
        } 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: it probably never reaches your second condition... did you put a break point there?

Comment: My only CSS rule is:
    #hide-homepage {display:none;}

I tried to do it with CSS alone, but there are times when I want the div to show & hide when the screen width is greater than 992px, depending upon the content.  I'm fairly new to JS, so I know there is probably a better way of doing it.

Comment: I'm also getting "showMyDiv is not defined" as an error in FF.  I thought a function declaration didn't need to be defined.

Comment: [FIXED]  I just used an anonymous function instead and the error went away.

Comment: I never mentioned CSS, what I'm trying to say is you should debug it, put a breakpoint just before the second condition, and then in the watch expressions, check what window.location.href is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (window.location.href == "http://wgzrv.ndxva.servertrust.com") && (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 992) {
```

should be

```
    if (window.location.href == "http://wgzrv.ndxva.servertrust.com" && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 992) {
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'd vote you up, but my rep isn't high enough yet.

Comment: It actually didn't affect the script, but it did make a FF script error go away.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of == using indexOf()

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(window).resize(function(){ 
    function showMyDiv() {
    if (window.location.href == "http://wgzrv.ndxva.servertrust.com") && (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 992) { 
    document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="none";
    } else if (window.location.href.indexOf("http://wgzrv.ndxva.servertrust.com/login.asp") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="none";
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 992) {
    document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="none";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="block";
        }
    } 
});
</script>
```

EDIT (I removed the inner function, didn't see it the first time):

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(window).resize(function(){ 
    if (window.location.href == "http://wgzrv.ndxva.servertrust.com") && (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 992) { 
    document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="none";
    } else if (window.location.href.indexOf("http://wgzrv.ndxva.servertrust.com/login.asp") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="none";
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 992) {
    document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="none";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("hide-homepage").style.display="block";
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that didn't hide it, either.

Comment: Try the edited version.  Basically you define a function on resize() event but don't really call it.